# Stay on page after submitting similar ajax-forms

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Maybe you can help as I have a - as I think - special problem with ajax.

**What I want to do**
I have a newsfeed and between the posts I show divs which contain forms, e.g. polls. Users should be allowed to interact and submit the result.

**What's the goal**
Users should interact, submit the result and stay on the page, see a result-text which I would show via JavaScript/jQuery.

**What's the problem?**
The divs with the elements are randomly created, so there are multiple elements similar to each other, just different (random) content. There are skill request and skill rating. I'd address the ID, but don't know how to do on a click.

**What do I have?**
The script works so far. I can successfully insert data into the table and I have a script that respects all "stock-scripts", but only reacts on the one which I have clicked on.

**Where's the code?**
This is my current code. 
These are the div-containers and the forms:

```
<div class="w3-white w3-center"><h3>Please rate '.$fname.' '.$lname.'&#039;s '.$skillname.'-skill '.$skid.'.</h3>
        <form name="skill_rating"   method="post" id="'.$lname.$skillname.'">
            <input type="hidden" name="sid" id="sid" value="'.$skid.'" />
            <input type="hidden" name="aid" id="aid" value="'.$aid.'" />

          <span>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" checked> 1
            <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2"> 2
            <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3"> 3
            <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4"> 4
            <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5"> 5
            <input type="radio" name="rating" value="6"> 6
            <input type="radio" name="rating" value="7"> 7
            <input type="radio" name="rating" value="8"> 8
            <input type="radio" name="rating" value="9"> 9
            <input type="radio" name="rating" value="10"> 10    <br>                                                                      
         </span>

         <input type="submit" name="submit" />

    </form>
</div>
```

And the second:

```
    <div class="w3-white w3-center"><h3>Does '.$conx_ufn.' '.$conx_uln.' have the skill '.$skill.'?</h3>
        <form id="'.$conx_usr.$skill_id.'" name="skill_request" class="skill_request" method="post">

                <input type="hidden" name="uid" value="'.$uid.'" />
                <input type="hidden" name="usr" value="'.$conx_usr.'" />
                <input type="hidden" name="skid" value="'.$skill_id.'" />           
                <span>
                  No
                  <input type="radio" name="vote" value="0">
                  Yes
                  <input type="radio" name="vote" value="1">
                </span>

                <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="submit" class="submit1">                                 
        </form>
    </div>
```

The script alone works as you see it right now. But it doesn't work when working with two functions for the two kinds of forms, even when using #skill_rating and #skill_request or try to address it different.

```
$(function () {

        $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

          e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'feed_skill_rating.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function () {
              alert('form was submitted');
            }
          });
        $(this).parent().removeClass("w3-white").css("background-color", "yellow").html("Thank you for the rating. You rated <? echo $fname ?> on a skill.");
        });

});
```

What would be a solution for this? I've tried some things, but till now with no success.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:Randall was right with the ID and through some kind of weirdness I assume I thought the ID-part wouldn't be possible. Wrong. It is. And I applied this to my code.

EDIT NOTICES: I added a script that is working if working alone. Changed the description.

Comment: This seems wrong: `$(form)` ... try `$("form[name='skill_request']")`. Also `$('skill_request')` should be the same. You really should just give that form a unique `id` and use that.

Comment: @Randall. To avoid every mistake: I replace every $(form) with $("form[name='skill_request']"), that's what you mean? Unfortunately not successful.

Comment: This is not a proper selector: `$('skill_request')`. This is also not a proper selector: `$(form)` ... because you never define `form`. "not working" is "not helpful".

Comment: Mh, but, for example, using class='skill_request' and then $('.class_request') doesn't result in not redirecting. Or did I get you wrong, Randall?
@Danny Fardy: Thanks for improvements.

Comment: Your HTML code has no any element with class attribute equals to `submit1`

Answer (score 0):

Also take the `action="feed_skill_request.php"` tag out of your current form.

```
$('#".$formId."').submit(function() {
    $.post('feed_skill_request.php', $(this).serialize(), function(res) {
        alert('Response from the form post: '+res)
        // $('#success-message').html(res)
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks @ethancrist, I tried your solution. Your code works so far as that I can insert the data after I made some changes to get the form's id. But the problem still exists and when removing the action-tag the script doesn't enter anything.

Comment: If you know what PHP variable the form is going to be, just do the same for the script part and echo the JS from PHP in `<script></script>` tags. I updated my code.

Comment: The `action` tag in a form is solely for the traditional way of doing things, i.e. refreshing the page and the HTML automatically sending the form without Javascript. You don't need it in your case, so long as the id of the form is correct, using jQuery `.submit()` will trigger when `<input type="submit">` is clicked.

Comment: Understood. I'll try this all tomorrow. It's late and then I will do this. Thanks so far.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks making the submit input type="button" will work

Comment: I mean in the html